# My camera is still dark after max brightness

Tags: 14.04, skype, camera, video4linux

I use mainly Skype and today i installed Ubuntu but my camera is dark. Ok. I searched how to increase max brightheess and i find 2 progrmas video4linux control panel and ldvc or something else. Ok. I set up max brightness to 255 and is darker than Camera on Windows, so dark to one people can see me correctly

My camera is a Microsoft Lifecam HD 3000. My version of Ubuntu is 14.04 LTS

---

**I solved searching on google and i find that**

### https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Webcam/Troubleshooting

My problem is a USB controller doesnt works fine when i use the tests,  change of usb controller and now works fine

Comment: Please add it in as an answer and upvote+accept it. That will make the question be marked as solved.

Answer (score 1):

If anyone having the same problem in **Ubuntu 20.04** then he can use this trick that works for me.I have faced this problem when using **Discord**,**Google Meet**,**Facebook video call**.

I am using a software to change my camera settings named **guvcview**.

At first, sometimes my webcam becomes **dark** and I used to open **guvcview** and make some changes in webcam setting like toggle `powerline frequencey` option and set it  **50hz/60hz/disable** and then the webcam becomes normal.

Then one day i installed **Discord** and now the darker problem is happening every time I use my webcam like **google meet** , **Facebook video chat** etc.

I have searched a lot and tried every solutions but didn't work for me.

Then I did some **experiments** and find a **weird** solution :

Before using webcam in any software I toggle the `powerline frequencey` option and then open **Facebook video call** where the cam is not darker amd i is normal. Then I open **Google meet** and that's how it worked for me.

Though i couldn't find any **permanent** solution but it's working fine and you have to do it everytime you go for a google meet **meeting**.

I know my solution sounds weird but If you are facing this issue then have a try and if you find any better solution then please inform me.

Answer (score 0):

Most webcams have autofocus, but the sensor doesn't work in low light. Turn on your webcam with the Chesse app and shine a lamp above the camera (your smartphone's flashlight can do the trick) for five seconds and voilá. The autofocus sensor will balance the brightness.