# Dark Camera picture/video Lenovo B570e

Tags: drivers, 16.04, lenovo, camera

I have **Lenovo B570e** laptop running Ubuntu 16.04 (kernel 4.4.0-45). My built-in **camera shows picture/video darker** than usual on cheese/skype.

However, the camera works well on Windows 7/10 OS.

I have tried `guvcview`. It only shows one device: `Lenovo EasyCamera`

`lsusb` prints the following:

```
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 0bda:0139 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5139 Card Reader Controller
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 5986:0292 Acer, Inc 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

I have this issue on every previous  (13.04, 14.04) and current Ubuntu (16.04) version. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Check the [Answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1279232/844087) in this question.
This can be help full if someone still facing the same problem in **Ubuntu 2020**.

Answer (score 0):

Using Synaptic, install **v4lucp** and you can adjust your brightness there.

Start Synaptic from the dash, click the RELOAD icon, click the SEARCH icon, enter v4lucp, in the results pane, mark 4vlucp for installation, click the APPLY icon, then quit Synaptic.

Go to the dash and open v4lucp and have fun!

Cheers, Al

Comment: Thanks for help. Just to point out that, **v4lucp** has similar controls as I had with **guvcview**.